# Can I modify the default fit behavior of the right-click box selection

Tags: lightningchart

LightningChart Version: 4.0.2.

Now the right-click box selection will adaptively zoom to all the data visible, but I want the Y-axis of the chart to be blank at the top and bottom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLH9Y.png)

By the way, can I get the right click event on the y axis? I found single and double click events